# What does $L^2$(R) mean?

Tags: wavelets

I am reading about wavelets and it mentions something about "a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$". What does that even mean?

Comment: It means the square of the function has finite integral

Comment: It means square-integrable. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)

Comment: It means the functional space with elements integral of square over the entire real numbers of which is finite. $f \in L^2 (\mathbb R): \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^2 dx < M$.

Comment: @Kaster $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 dx < + \infty$ is more precise.

Comment: What are L and R here?

Comment: It means you probably need to learn some real analysis (measure theory and a little bit of Fourier analysis) before trying to learn about wavelets...

Comment: The $L$ stands for Lebesgue, and $\Bbb R$ denotes the real numbers. If you aren't even familiar with the notation $\Bbb R$, then I second Ulrich that you need to learn some basics first.

Comment: The L is for Lebesgue integration

Comment: I did do fourier analysis in my MEng Electronic Engineering degree so I am familiar with R and Z and other things. But I am not sure about L and was not sure if this R is the R I think it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$L^2(R)$ likely denotes the space of [square-integrable functions on $R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function).